# I got issues writing a string in a txt file using swift XCode 7

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to develop an app for Apple Watch and I'm dealing with some issues doing a very simple task. I want to write inside a txt file once the view is loaded. I use this code here:

```
let FNAME = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("helloFile", ofType: "txt")!

let xx = "hello"

do {  try xx.writeToFile(FNAME, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) }
catch { }
```

Everything works just fine, on runtime i can read from the txt and the text just changes properly. But once i stop the app running in the simulator the txt file doesn't maintain the changes. So when the view is again loaded the content of the file is the not "hello".

Why that? Is there something wrong with the code I wrote here?

Comment: On devices, files in the application bundle are **not writable**.

Comment: What could be a solution for that? The answer the guy gave in the question you posted is not so clear. @MartinR

Comment: @MartinR I'm looking for some informations about the 'Document folder'. I'll see thank you.